# How to change .ui-slider-handle background-img dynamically with JQM slider/range

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, slider, range

I would like to change the background-image:url of the ui-slider-handle depending on the value of the range/slider (JQuery Mobile)

Roughly like that http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/YgJ9P/2/ but, as I said, I would like to see the background-img of the slider-handle changing.

```
$("#slider").change(function() {
    sVal = $(this).val();

    if(sVal > 21 && sVal <= 40) {
        $('#theImage').attr('src', 'http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/21-skull.png');
    }

    if(sVal > 41 && sVal <= 60) {
        $('#theImage').attr('src', 'http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/18-envelope.png');
    }

    if(sVal > 61 && sVal <= 80) {
        $('#theImage').attr('src', 'http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/100-coffee.png');
    }

    if(sVal > 81 && sVal <= 100) {
        $('#theImage').attr('src', 'http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/88-beermug.png');
    }

});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to select the handle element rather than the one Phill selected in his JSFiddle:

```
$("#slider").change(function() {
   var sVal = $(this).val(),
       $ele = $(this).next().children();

    if(sVal > 21 && sVal <= 40) {
        $ele.addClass('skull-class').removeClass('envelope-class coffee-class beermug-class');
    }

    if(sVal > 41 && sVal <= 60) {
        $ele.addClass('envelope-class').removeClass('skull-class coffee-class beermug-class');
    }

    if(sVal > 61 && sVal <= 80) {
        $ele.addClass('coffee-class').removeClass('envelope-class skull-class beermug-class');
    }

    if(sVal > 81 && sVal <= 100) {
        $ele.addClass('beermug-class').removeClass('envelope-class coffee-class skull-class');
    }

});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/YgJ9P/192/

Rather than use `.css()` to add styling to the element, I setup some classes to keep my JS code and my CSS code separate:

```
.ui-slider .skull-class {
    background : url(http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/21-skull.png);
}
.ui-slider .envelope-class {
    background : url(http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/18-envelope.png);
}
.ui-slider .coffee-class {
    background : url(http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/100-coffee.png);
}
.ui-slider .beermug-class {
    background : url(http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/88-beermug.png);
}​
```

You can also condense the JS a bit:

```
var allClasses = 'skull-class envelope-class coffee-class beermug-class';
$("#slider").change(function() {

    //get the value of the slider as well as cache the slider handle element
    var sVal = $(this).val(),
        $ele = $(this).next().children();

    //remove the icon classes from the handle
    $ele.removeClass(allClasses);

    (sVal > 21 && sVal <= 40) ? $ele.addClass('skull-class') :
        (sVal > 41 && sVal <= 60) ? $ele.addClass('envelope-class') :
            (sVal > 61 && sVal <= 80) ? $ele.addClass('coffee-class') : 
                (sVal > 81 && sVal <= 100) ? $ele.addClass('beermug-class') : ''
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/YgJ9P/195/

Comment: Thanks alot! Any hint or nice reads for using more than one of those sliders within the same data-role="content"?

Comment: You just need to change the `#slider` selector to select all the sliders, which could be: `input[data-type="range"]`. And that's it, other than the selector, the JS is self contained and works relatively to itself. Also, if you found this answer helpful, don't be afraid to accept it or up-vote it.

Comment: Now I'd like to add tooltips aswell (depending on the position of the slider) but I get stuck. I tried to solve this with `$("#slider").attr('title', 'hover-text');` but failed. [sorry, I am not able to up-vote, because I do not have enough credits]